# QNetworkAccessManager does not emit signal

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

So I have this code:

```
QUrl url("http://...");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
QNetworkReply *reply = m_networkManager->get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(onRequestCompleted()));
connect(reply,SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),SLOT(onError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

and I cant get signal to the other fuction

```
void IpResolver::onRequestCompleted()
{
QString webContent;

QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

if (reply)
{
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QString webContent = reply->readAll();
    }
}
}
```

I cant figure out the solution, help please.

Comment: Your topic "QNetworkAccessManager does not work" is false. I have used that class many times and while it does have some issues, saying "it does not work" is blatantly false. Saying "I can't figure out how to use it correctly" would be closer to the truth.

Comment: okay I am gonna rename it

Comment: "Can't get signal to the other function" you mean your slot is never called?

Comment: Yes, slot onRequestComlpleted is never called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want, but:

1. Why do you use reply pointer instead of some kind     `onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply)`?
2. If you do so:

   ```
   QUrl url("http://...");
   QNetworkRequest request(url);
   connect(m_networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &IpResolver::onRequestCompleted);
   m_networkManager->get(request);
   ```
3. And your slot will be, for example:

   ```
   void IpResolver::onRequestCompleted(QNetworkReply *reply)
   {
       QString webContent;
       if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
           webContent = reply->readAll();
   }
   ```

Comment: At first, thanks a lot for help but I tried your version and now it throws exception when compiled: Exception thrown: read access violation.

this-> was 0x555C3A43.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Where exactly you catching an exception? What debug mode telling you?

Comment: Here I catch the exception: QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::get(const QNetworkRequest &request)
{
    return d_func()->postProcess(createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation, request));
}

Comment: Does exception throws when you're doing `m_networkManager->get(request);`? If you comment this is everything alright then? Is it `First-chance exception at: The binding handle is invalid.`?

Comment: Well, I commented it and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: OK, can you find which line throw this exception in your code?

Comment: In code its this line:     connect(m_networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &IpResolver::onRequestCompleted);

Comment: Hey I found a mistake in my code and also the webpage I was trying to get was down, so thanks everyone. P.S. now it works